# edit the maximum length of \hfill

Tags: spacing, hfill

Similar to [edit the minimum length of \hfill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306427/edit-the-minimum-length-of-hfill), but I want to keep a maximum spacing so that elements are not too separated. I also need two other `\hfill` to center the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\smarthfill}{\hfill} % change this

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill1\smarthfill2\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
should work as
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill1\qquad2\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

while
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
should work as
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

more tests:
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.40\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfill\rule{0.40\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.40\textwidth}{10pt}\hfill\rule{0.40\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfill\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfill\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10pt}\hfill\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10pt}\hfill\rule{0.25\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: note `} \hfill \rule..`  is putting a word space before (but not after) the hfill, so the minimum space is not 0, is that intended?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no. I intend to make two boxes that almost fill a line.

Comment: don't put a space before `\hfill` (or `\smarthfill`)  (or `\hspace*{\fill}`) then.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle updated

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you want

```
\newcommand{\smarthfill}{\hspace{2em minus 2em}} % change this
```

so a space of 2em that will shrink to 0pt if needed.

If you want the space to balance with the outer spaces you need to make them all have the same (finite) stretch component,  so replacing hfill by hspace 0pt plus .5\textwidth for example, you will see the "b" version on line 3 of each figure is quite close to your requested spacing (on line 4).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand{\smarthfill}{\hfill} % change this
\newcommand{\smarthfilla}{\nolinebreak\hspace{2em minus 2em}} % change this
\newcommand{\smarthfillb}{\nolinebreak\hspace{.1em plus 1.9em}} % change this

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
X\dotfill X

\hfill1\smarthfill2\hspace*{\fill}

\hfill1\smarthfilla2\hspace*{\fill}

\hspace*{0pt plus.5\textwidth}1\smarthfillb2\hspace*{0pt plus.5\textwidth}\hspace*{-0pt plus -1fil}

\hfill1\qquad2\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

while
\begin{figure}[H]
\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}

\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfilla\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}

\hspace*{0pt plus.5\textwidth}\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\smarthfillb\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{0pt plus.5\textwidth}\hspace*{-0pt plus -1fil}

\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hfill\rule{0.49\textwidth}{10pt}\hspace*{\fill}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The space is too small in the first example and too big in the second. I also try to change the two lengths you specify but fail to get the two examples work at the same time. The two `\hfill` at the ends of the line should match `\smarthfill` in the second example.

Comment: @putianyi888 oh sorry I misread, you had `\qquad` not `\quad` so this should be 2em, I will update the answer

Comment: if you want _exactly_ what you say you probably need to specify an algorithm rather than just two example points, the answer here is most natural tex box-and-glue answer, to maximize the space to 2em but allow to shrink to 0 if the boxes are large

Comment: @putianyi888 see update

Comment: I can accept a solution which looks nice enough rather than being accurate. I've added two more tests where your solution has too small spaces. Technically I'm open to an algorithm, but I have no experience on that.